# new iOS 11 scroll view contentLayoutGuide not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, ios11

I am trying to make a photo viewer similar to the Photo's app where the user can zoom in and out on a particular image.

The image is initially sized so fit on the screen but when zoomed can expand to cover the entire screen.

I have this happening in a collectionView cell which is the size of the screen and has paging enabled.  In that cell is a scrollView with storyboard constraints set to top/bottom/leading/trailing to it's superview.  The rest happens in the code below which is the custom cell.

According to the new behavior of the scrollView introduced in iOS 11, the contentView (imageView in my case) should be centered in the scrollView using:

```
imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

However I don't see it explained anywhere and adding those two lines to my code do absolutely nothing.

The imageView inside the scrollView continues to be positioned in the top left corner.

Hopefully somebody has figured out how to do this and can help.

```
import UIKit

class ImageCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView! {
        didSet {
            scrollView.delegate = self
            scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.2
            scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 2.0
            scrollView.contentSize = imageView.frame.size
            scrollView.addSubview(imageView)

            imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 350).isActive = true
            imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 350).isActive = true

            imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
            imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        }
    }

    var imageView = UIImageView()

    var image: UIImage? {
        get {
            return imageView.image
        }
        set {
            imageView.image = newValue
            scrollView?.contentSize = imageView.frame.size
        }
    }

    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return self.imageView
    }

}
```

Comment: I find that it does not work in iOS 11, see https://github.com/onmyway133/blog/issues/371

Answer (score 1):

I have been facing the same problem for about a day, and I finally figured it out. It is not sufficient to just add the width and height constraints to the image. For this to work using `contentLayoutGuide`, the image view actually has to be the same size as the scroll view. Therefore, you will have to do either of the following:

**Option 1**

Change the width and height constraints of the image view to be the same size as the scroll view.

```
imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: scrollView.bounds.width).isActive = true
imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: scrollView.bounds.height).isActive = true
```

**Option 2** - Preferred

Remove the width and height constraints for the image view. Instead, add constraints pinning the top, bottom, leading, and trailing anchors of the image view to the scroll view. I tried both, and this method seemed to work the best.

```
imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Depending on how/where you are using this, you may need to use `scrollView.layoutMarginGuide` for the anchor.

I would also recommend moving this code from `didSet` to a private method named `setup()`, or something along those lines. Then, from `viewWillAppear`, call `setup()`. This is a more consistent way of doing it. Hope this helped!